# F# list find item index

Tags: list, f#, boolean

So I've got 2 lists. 1 is a list booleans, the other is a list of data.
Is there a way of getting the index for every false value in the boolean list, so I can then use those index's to find values in my list of data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `List.choose` function does a map and filter in one pass, and so avoids creating one of the intermediate lists created by Bartek's answer:

```
List.zip booleans values
|> List.choose (function (false, v) -> Some v | _ -> None)
```

If only there was a `List.choose2`, then we wouldn't need to zip either!

Comment: This one actually works better for me because I can change the false to true which is something I've realized I need to do for my current project.

Answer (score 9):

If your list are the same length you can zip them (make a new list that contains pairs of (switch * value) and then filter that new list grabbing only those pairs that have false in the first element.

```
List.zip booleans values
|> List.filter (fst >> not)
// grab only values
|> List.map snd
```